# Getting SASS to work with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass

I am trying to get SASS to work with Rails 3.
I have added `gem 'haml'` to my `Gemfile` (and ran `bundle install`) and I have added a `styles.scss` to my `public/` directory, but it does not seem to be working. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, Sass expects sass/scss files to go in `public/stylesheets/sass`, which are then compiled into css files in public. You can change this path by setting `Sass::Plugin.options[:template_location]` in your config, though.